# Explanation for "_lf_" and "_lfno_" pattern in Java8.g8 grammar for ANTLR4

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I'm working with a recogniser built from the [Java8.g8](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java8/Java8.g4) grammar with [ANTLR4](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4). This grammar splits up some rules into subrules with `_lf_` and sometimes `_lfno_` connecting suffixes — here is one of the simpler examples:

```
fieldAccess
    :   primary '.' Identifier
    |   'super' '.' Identifier
    |   typeName '.' 'super' '.' Identifier
    ;

fieldAccess_lf_primary
    :   '.' Identifier
    ;

fieldAccess_lfno_primary
    :   'super' '.' Identifier
    |   typeName '.' 'super' '.' Identifier
    ;
```

...and this rule is the scariest: `primaryNoNewArray_lfno_primary_lfno_arrayAccess_lfno_primary`.

To process the java files, I am making transforms in listener functions that match the rules, and to do the right thing I need to understand the rules, and that also means being able to vocalise them.

1. Does anyone know what these `_lf_` and `_lfno_` segments stand for, or what they are an acronym for and how I could read them out aloud?
2. Can anyone shed light on what they are trying to do, and why they are necessary?

(My best guess is that they are forcing a switch in the way the parse tree is formed - two way for the `fieldAccess` example, eight way for the `primary...` rule - but other than that, I'm pretty mystified. A scan of the ANTLR4 reference doesn't immediately throw up any answers, and `grep` only finds this pattern in [Java8.g8](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java8/Java8.g4) and not any of the other [grammars](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4).)

Any help very much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Ok, I guess the answer to 2b) is ANTLR4 can't handle sets of rules that left-recurse together like this from [jls8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf).p700 (rewritten in antlr form): `ClassOrInterfaceType : ClassType | InterfaceType` and `ClassType : ( ClassOrInterfaceType '.' )? Annotation* Identifier TypeArguments?`. Still need help with the what, how and naming/how-to-read. /cc @samharwell ping...?

Comment: Even more mystifying is the fact that some of the parser rules have no productions. For example, here's an entire parser rule from java8.g4:  

`primaryNoNewArray_lf_arrayAccess
    :
    ;`  

Is this correct, or is it just an incomplete grammar rule? I'm writing a visitor pattern Java 8 utility and this has me really stymied.